# How i can add action-button after right bottom side of table in django.admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

How i can add action-button after right bottom side of table in django.admin?

I know, that i can add action into the list on left top side of table (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/actions/), but how i can do like this

[image]

Can i do this without editing admin templates?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that not really. You'll need to override admin templates, but it is not much hassle, as:

- You can override them for each model separately (or for whole site).
- You can override template for model X, and then inherit from base template, changing only what you want.

You'll need to override template for this model, inherit it from the default template and add button you want. Consult [this manual page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates). Actuall you will need to override 'change_list.html' template, and change will be really similar [to this one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template). As `change_list.html` contains block `object-tools` and put button code there.